# Netbeans 7 how to flag jdk

Tags: netbeans, java, flags

Another Java/Netbeans-Newbie-question: I've started looking into swt, but having some trouble getting it to work in Netbeans. In Eclipse, it works fine though after setting forcing the 32-bit-version.

Where can I add the flags (i.e. -d32) to the jdk1.6 settings? I figured it would be in MyProject/Properties/Libraries (at least, here I can set 1.6), but I can't flag here.
Any hints appreciated!

Thnx in advance,
Marcus

Comment: Do you need that flag to run your application or to run NetBeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the 32-bit JDK 1.6 as one of the Java platforms by opening the "Java Platform Manager" dialog

```
Tools->Java Platforms->Add Platform...
```

and pointing it to your 32-bit JDK 1.6 path.

Then you can let your project use the platform you added

```
(right-click project)->Properties->Libraries->Java Platform
```

There is also a "Manage Platforms" button on the above dialog in the project properties that will take you directly to the "Java Platform Manager" dialog.